# Service bus configuração

Tags: c#, web-service, wcf, microsoft-azure

Vou tentar detalhar o meu problema, tenho projeto WCF hospedado no IIS com a opção auto start habilitada do app fabric configurada mas mesmo assim o projeto só inicia no relay do azure quando acesso a url do serviço...

Depois de um tempo o relay desaparece.

IIS 8 Auto fabric 1.1 VS 2013

Posteriormente irei publicar no azure -> web application.

```
 <service name="Nobre.Service.RelayService">        
        <endpoint address="https://nobre-queue-test.servicebus.windows.net/servicerelay/" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="sharedSecretClientCredentials" 
                  binding="basicHttpRelayBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpRelayEndpointConfig"
                  name="RelayEndpoint" contract="Nobre.Domain.IRelayService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpRelayBinding>
        <binding name="HttpRelayEndpointConfig">
          <security mode="None" relayClientAuthenticationType="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpRelayBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="http">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="https">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="RelayEndpoint" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="sharedSecretClientCredentials">    
          <serviceRegistrySettings discoveryMode="Public" displayName="ServiceRelay" />
          <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
            <tokenProvider>
              <sharedAccessSignature keyName="RootManageSharedAccessKey" key="CHAVE" />
            </tokenProvider>
          </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>


<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
Projeto de Test

app.config

  <client>      
      <endpoint name="RelayEndpoint"
                contract="Nobre.Domain.IRelayService"
                address="https://nobre-queue-test.servicebus.windows.net/ServiceRelay/" 
                behaviorConfiguration="sharedSecretClientCredentials"
                binding="basicHttpRelayBinding" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="sharedSecretClientCredentials">
          <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
            <tokenProvider>
              <sharedAccessSignature keyName="RootManageSharedAccessKey" key="+CHAVE=" />
            </tokenProvider>
          </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


var cf = new ChannelFactory<IRelayService>("RelayEndpoint");
var ch = cf.CreateChannel() ;

string result = ch.DoWork("hello");
```

Erro ao executar o test.

{"There was no endpoint listening at https://nobre-queue-test.servicebus.windows.net/ServiceRelay/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."}

{"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Comment: Olá, Wandelson, tudo tranquilo? Olha só, o artigo que você seguiu como exemplo é um pouco antigo acredito que você pode obter mais sucesso lendo/seguindo este artigo aqui http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/ e/ou https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee173579.aspx Caso eu tenha entendi errado a sua necessidade, compartilhe o código/solução que está com problema que eu terei prazer em te ajudar. Forte abraço.

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?